# Django Integrity Error 1452, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: python, mysql, django

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Line(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)

class Line2 (models.Model):
  text_line = models.ForeignKey ("Line", primary_key = True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
from models import Line, Line2

def test_page (request):
  if 'uid' in request.POST:
    user_id = request.POST['uid']
    line_query = Line.objects.get (text = user_id)
    new_entry = Line2 (text_line_id = line_query)
    new_entry.save()
    return render(request, "templateFiles/testPage1.html", {"page_result":"Data Entered"});
  else:
    return render(request, "templateFiles/testPage1.html")
```

template:

```
<div id = "header">
  {{ page_result }}
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_page/" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

The data which I'm sending exists in the parent key, but I'm getting

IntegrityError

> (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tempDB`.`testDBProjectApp_line2`, CONSTRAINT `text_line_id_refs_text_f741df88` FOREIGN KEY (`text_line_id`) REFERENCES `testDBProjectApp_line` (`text`))')

My Database Parent Table "line" is as follows:

```
 mysql> select * from testDBProjectApp_line;
 +-------+
 | text  |
 +-------+
 | test1 |
 | test2 |
 +-------+
```

Comment: Even if there was provision for that(I don't know), it really wouldn't make sense. A parent relation tuple can be referenced by multiple child relation tuples - thereby breaking the uniqueness constraint that comes with a primary key. you shoul probably change `primary_key = True` to `unique=True`

Comment: In Django, declaring a model without primary key results in creating a automatic "id" field and set it as the primary key. What if i don't want an extra column?

I created one more model and it is working fine. But i wonder why others are not working.


There's one more observation:
If i try "new_entry = Line2 (text_line_id = 'text1')"  (i.e. with a constant value), it works absolutely fine.
I've also checked the values coming from HTML template, and they are also correct.

Comment: I tried deleting the database multiple times, changing the column names and then running syncdb. Nothing worked!!

I did:

mysql> drop database tempDB;
mysql> create database tempDB;

$sudo python manage.py syncdb

Comment: As far as i can see there is no such migration directory or file in my project directory...

Comment: oh sorry i didnt noticed that...change `text_line_id = line_query` to `text_line= line_query` will solve

Comment: thanks itzmeontv... it worked by adding ".text" in new_entry = Line2 (text_line_id = line_query.text), if you remove "_id" from text_line_id it throws an error "Cannot assign "u'test2'": "Line.text" must be a "Line2" instance. This error is because in Line2 the foreignKey name is "text_id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't assign the `Line` instance to `text_line_id` as you are currently doing.

You should either do

```
new_entry = Line2(text_line=line_query)
```

or

```
new_entry = Line2(text_line_id=line_query.text)
```

Comment: i didnt noticed that :p

Comment: Bingo!! that worked... Thanks Alasdir and itzmeontv :)
I was not using the "text" attribute of the table.

Still wondering, in other app it is working without it.
"new_project = projects_list (project_id = proj_id, project_name = proj_name, project_owner = personal_details (user_id = proj_owner), project_creation_date = current_date)"

Comment: Glad it solved your problem :) Code in the comments is very difficult to understand, I can't tell what was different about that app.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with giving the foreign key to related_name.

also verify this:
Is the parents table have a record which you are filtering from query.